# Image is not showing when sharing on Facebook due to Gzip

Tags: joomla-3.x, facebook, gzip

I am having site on Joomla 3.3. Whenever i share article on facebook, it dosent fetch image. So googled and found that gzip is causing problem. so i turned it off and checked, all images were displaying properly while sharing.

I want gzip enabled, but if i do facebook wont show images. Can someone please help? Currently my gzip is off. here is my site: livemedia24.com

Comment: How are you sharing the article, using a plugin/component? If so which one.

Comment: I am using K2 Article latest 2.6.8. Facebook is displaying image while sharing but if gzip is disabled. I even search on google, many people are facing this problem but no solution. I am simply sharing url on image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known Facebook bug. There exists a Joomla plugin which allows to work around it. I think by disabling GZip if the request comes from Facebook.

I think the plugin is on JED. Of you can't find it I can look it up later.

Comment: I have tried this http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/27725 but not useful for me. There are only two plugin for this problem. one is gzip control and other one is facebookfix. ficebookfix is old one and developer recommended to use gzip control but gzip is not working with gzip disable. Can you help me further?

Comment: The Faceboofix one was the one I meant. But the other one is coming from the same developer, so it should be fine.
Please check with the developer why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I think the Social Meta Tags plugin works around this issue so you can still use gzip. See  https://github.com/hans2103/pkg_SocialMetaTags

Comment: I use [Gzip Control](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/gzip-control/) for this purpose. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to debug an issue with Facebook is via the **Open Graph Debugger**:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=livemedia24.com

Your site is showing several alternative images now.

Comment: thanks. but facebook share image show if gzip is disabled. so it seem joomla bug